# Can't connect to IIS site on network IP

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012-r2

I've got a Server 2012 R2 box with IIS on it. I can't connect to the default website on the server's IP address. It stopped working after I disjoined one domain and joined another (not sure if this is related).

I can only connect to the site via *localhost*

**Things I've checked**

- The default website is bound to `*:80`. I've also tried binding it to the public IP only
- `netsh show iplisten` is empty (which should mean bind to all IPs)
- `netstat -an` shows IIS listening on 0.0.0.0:80
- I **can** telnet to `localhost 80`, but **cannot** telnet to `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 80`
- I can also telnet to `hostname 80` where `hostname` resolves to an link-local IPv6 address
- I've checked the IP is correct (I'm RDPing to it)
- I've disabled the windows firewall

What could cause this?

Comment: Have you performed an IIS Reset or rebooted the box?

Comment: @Kate yes to both

Comment: IIS is so weird. Did you flip back to the original Domain and see if it works? Also, were you using DNS or anything tied to the old domain?

Comment: The original domain was deleted so no can do. DNS is pointing at new domain, and I'm querying straight IP addresses so that shouldn't be a factor

Answer (score 1):

Well, I didn't manage to figure it out so I just deployed a new server from scratch. Chock that one up to the strange books.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and created the netsh listen to get it working.

```
C:\>netsh

netsh>http

add iplisten ipaddress=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

exit
```

Answer (score 0):

Try binding new IP using the instruction given in "[Add and Remove IP Address Bindings](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb734869.aspx)", which includes the steps to add new IP to your website in IIS.

Comment: It gives the steps to add new IP to your website in IIS